# How to access OData URLs with authentication

Tags: api, authentication, odata

I have a OData Server which returns me a json.
When I accessing the URL through a browser i need to input the username/password.
Doesn't accept the entries which I do in the pop-up. Need to cancel it and then it shows me a dialog box after which i can see the required json.

I am not able to figure out the kind of authentication in use.

Using basic authentication in Postman client is not working. 
Any suggestions as to how do I go about using this URL both in postman and inside an Anuglar JS or Node JS program.

Comment: If it is rest api, it should support some other authentication system. like token authentication. Is it difficult to ask which authentication is in used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the input.

But I got access to the code implementation which is accessing the URI which I want.

So There is a Sharepoint/C# application in the universe which is doing a Forms based authentication to get the data required. :/

Will try to reverse engineer that get it working in my Node App.

Cheers. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can install interceptor in postman. Go to cookies tab next to body and install the interceptor then turn it on.After installing interceptor you can login with your user/pass and then send your request.

See this picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fdZH.png)

Comment: Installed the interceptor, Where do I add the username/password exactly. Sorry noob to the API world

Comment: just login with your website or send request to login service and postman automatically take the cookie and set it for you.